# Is there a way to query custom DNS server for DNS requests in Swift or ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dns

For one of my projects I need a way to query custom DNS server. However I'm way to far from this knowledge to do it by myself, without any help. Last few days I was reading lots of similar questions, but the only helpful thing that I found was how to create a VPN and assign it custom DNS. As I don't need VPN, but just to query a custom DNS I need your help, network gurus. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to follow the same technique than DNS Override app.
It's explained here:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/217490#217490
Use NEVPNManager and modify useDNSServers.
I tried and it works.

Comment: Do you have any demo? Above url isn't working.